# Hiding Cookies in Browsers

Tags: security, cookies, load-balancing

Am setting some `Cookies` using below code,

```
document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
```

Is there any way to hide them (end User should not be able to see them by checking the `Cookies` stored in their browsers)?

My Domain is accessed through a Load Balancer. If not through my code, in any ways it can be achieved through LB?

This question is raised keeping security aspects in mind.

Comment: encrypt them before storing.

Comment: @UsmanSaleem Ya one way. But, encrypted `Cookie` will also gets displayed on the Browser. Am not rejecting your answer, but, it doesn't answer to my question still.

Comment: cookies are meant to be stored on client and meant to store temporary and non-critical information. You can mark your cookies to be "secured" which will make sure that client (browser) will ask them on SSL, however, at the end of the day, they will be visible at the client. Encrypting cookie contents is achieved by virtually all custom web programming today. So the answer of your question "Is there any way to hide them" is No!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are creating your cookies on the browser, then unfortunately there is no way to "hide" them or more specifically the data within them.

Depending on your requirements, you could implement "security through obscurity" by doing some encryption in javascript (eg. http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/aes.html). **This is by no means secure**, but hides the cookie contents from the casual observer and non-technical sticky noses. Eg:

```
document.cookie = name + "=" + Aes.Ctr.encrypt(value + expires, yourPassword, 256) + "; path=/";
```

As @Usman Saleem commented, the only way to effectively make the cookie contents unreadable is to encrypt it on the server, before sending to the client.

Comment: Please, emphasize that it is not secure, and I'm not a fan of proposing non secure solutions. Present a secure one or none at all. Because someone may not read it and think that's the solution, and as you said it is not. So next time try to avoid presenting those schemes.

Comment: I'm not sure how much more I can emphasise that the solution is not secure. I've put the line in bold as well. I have also mentioned it twice in my answer.

Answer (score -2):

2 things:

1) Why would you need to do this?

2) I don't think this is possible

Comment: As mentioned in my question, "This question is raised keeping security aspects in mind."